# How to submit a form data without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried submitting form data without reloading the page using a submit event check. Below is my piece of code:

```
$( "#my-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
            //event.preventDefault();
            return false;
                });
```

Due to this page refresh has been stopped. But the action mapping to the form is not getting called. Is there any way that I can call the action and submit data without reloading page.

Comment: have you considered using AJAX?

Comment: calling through ajax doesn't send Jsession Id in request header, since my page domain and Ajax request are in http and https domain. So i didn't consider that approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the submit handler you have to make an ajax call that serializes the form data and sends it over. Adding `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` avoid the page refresh

See this [Submit form via AJAX in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557761/submit-form-via-ajax-in-jquery)